# Python Selenium how to target an h3 tag within a specific div?

Tags: python, selenium

I have several h3 tags within a page, none of them have a class or id to target but a specific one that I need is within another larger div. The code is below:

```
<div class="profile-info">
     <div class="photo-wrapper">
     </div>
     <h3>
     Text I need
     </h3>

</div>
```

How do I target and save the text within that h3 tag?

Comment: through css selector would be like --> go to parent and then next sibling. So this will give you the text `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.photo-wrapper+h3').text `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If class `photo-wrapper` is unique.

You can use below xpath :

```
//div[@class='photo-wrapper']//following-sibling::h3
```

if there are more than one h3 tag, please use xpath indexing:

```
(//div[@class='photo-wrapper']//following-sibling::h3)[1]
```

to represent first child `h3`.. `[2]` for second `h3` and so on..

or using **child :**

```
//div[@class='profile-info']//child::h3
```

to locate the first child under div which has `profile-info` class.

```
(//div[@class='profile-info']//child::h3)[1]
```

to represent first element as well with xpath indexing.

```
(//div[@class='profile-info']//child::h3)[2]
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.